# Bookmark to toggles lower nested levels

Tags: pdftex, hyperref, bookmarks

I am importing bookmarks to an existing PDF with bookmark package.

I want bookmark of level=0 to do no action except to be a clickable link that expands/collapses bookmarks nested in it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[
  pdfpagelabels=true,
  pdftitle={Optimization},
  pdfauthor={x}
]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\includepdf[pages=1-5]{example.pdf}

\bookmark[named=s, level=0]{Letter A}
\bookmark[page=1,level=1]{Ab}
\bookmark[page=2,level=1]{Ac}

\bookmark[named=s, level=0]{Letter B}
\bookmark[page=3, level=1]{Ba}
\bookmark[page=4, level=1]{Bb}

\end{document}
```

Currently with above code `named=s` I get a passive link that performs nothing when opened with a PDF reader in Windows 7. However, with PDF readers in mobile tablets for some reason it takes to the first page of the PDF. Please note that nothing is special with s in `named=s`.

What I want is that it functions as a button that collapses/expands nested bookmarks. For example, if `Letter A` is clicked then it simply expands to reveal bookmarks of `Ab` and `Ab`. If clicked again it collapses them.

Comment: I also get that `Letter A` and `Letter B` are *not* hyperlinks, but instead can just be expanded/collapsed. This seems reader/viewer dependent rather than anything to do with (La)TeX.

Comment: ...under SumatraPDF.

Comment: Same thing with SumatraPDF.

Comment: All I want to know what to pass as an argument into \bookmark[named=s, level=0]{Letter A}  instead of named=s to make it work.

Comment: Which mobile readers? Again, this seems reader-specific (mobile or not) and not related to (La)TeX.

Comment: Werner, I am not looking for a reader. This is a request for a code that performs collapse/expand action.

Comment: Sure. Your code already achieves that under SumatraPDF. Done.

Comment: It does NOT. Please get it. Any PDF bookmark under any good reader performs what your Sumatra does. Left edge of parent bookmark acts as an expand/collapse button, but the problem is to make ALL OF IT act as an collapse/expand button and NOT JUST left corner.

Comment: Oh, so you mean clicking on the actual text, not just the expand/collapse + sign? By the way [this is the bookmark view in SumatraPDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sfOy.png).

Comment: That's right. I want the text/title of the bookmark collapse/expand under one mouse click.

Comment: Ah, then this is definitely off-topic, since it has to do with the functionality of the reader, not with (La)TeX.

Comment: When you click on Ab in your PDF what does it do? It takes you to its linked page. Why can't parent title perform expand/collapse thing? I feel like there must be a code that goes into \bookmark[named=s, level=0]{Letter A}  instead of "named=s" that performs it. Maybe \bookmark[openlevel, level=0]{Letter A} ???

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51555/discussion-between-kitkat-and-werner).

Comment: Please reopen, I want to write an answer (a starting point with a bookmark that uses JavaScript).

Comment: @TeXnician Thanks for the reminder. The question is now answered.

Answer (score 3):

PDF viewers with support for Adobe Reader's JavaScript can collapse and open bookmarks by JavaScript. The action for the bookmark is specified as raw action code (option `rawaction`):

```
rawaction={%
  /S/JavaScript%
  /JS(event.target.open=!event.target.open)%
}
```

The target of the event is the bookmark that is clicked.

The following example defines and uses a style `top` for bookmarks at level 0 and the JavaScript action:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[
  pdfpagelabels=true,
  pdftitle={Optimization},
  pdfauthor={x}
]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\includepdf[pages=1-5]{example.pdf}

\bookmarkdefinestyle{top}{
  level=0,
  rawaction={%
    /S/JavaScript%
    /JS(event.target.open=!event.target.open)%
  },
}

\bookmark[style=top]{Letter A}
\bookmark[page=1,level=1]{Ab}
\bookmark[page=2,level=1]{Ac}

\bookmark[style=top]{Letter B}
\bookmark[page=3, level=1]{Ba}
\bookmark[page=4, level=1]{Bb}
\end{document}
```