# Open the bookmark but not all buttons?

Tags: bookmarks

I want open only the first button of tree

[image]

to create the levels i used this

```
\pdfbookmark[0]{Start}{start}
```

To close the others levels i use this

```
\hypersetup{
  bookmarksopen=false
}
```

but i get this result:

[image]

How open just the first button?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[pdftex, bookmarksnumbered,  pagebackref, colorlinks=true, citecolor=Blue, linkcolor=DarkBlue!30!Black, urlcolor=Black,bookmarksopen]{hyperref}
\makeindex[columns=3, title=Alphabetical Index, intoc]

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\cleardoublepage
\pdfbookmark{Dedicatory}{dedic}
\chapter*{Dedicatory}

   to all my family

\cleardoublepage
\pdfbookmark{Abstract}{abstr}

\chapter*{Abstract}

   hello world


\chapter{chapter}
\section{Introduction}
In this example several keywords\index{keywords} will be
used which are important and deserve to appear in the
Index\index{Index}.
 \subsection{subsection}
Terms like generate\index{generate} and some\index{others}
will also show up. Terms in the index can also be
nested \index{Index!nested}

\clearpage

\section{Second section}
This second section\index{section} may include some special
word, and expand the ones already used\index{keywords!used}.

\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you have more content *at the same level* as Start? Can you also just create a minimal document that compiles to your current output? Keep it minimal.

Comment: Have you seen this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/380706/29873

Comment: @Werner i edited my question see please

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I understand your request it was to have only the first level bookmarks open. Using your MWE, you can add `bookmarksopenlevel=0` as an option to `hyperref`. (If you want deeper levels open, you can change 0 to 1 or some other value.)

With this modification of your current MWE:

```
\usepackage[pdftex, bookmarksnumbered,  pagebackref, colorlinks=true, citecolor=Blue, linkcolor=DarkBlue!30!Black, urlcolor=Black,bookmarksopen,bookmarksopenlevel=0]{hyperref}
%
```

I get the display shown:
[image]

If I increase the depth by to 1, as follows

```
\usepackage[pdftex, bookmarksnumbered,  pagebackref, colorlinks=true, citecolor=Blue, linkcolor=DarkBlue!30!Black, urlcolor=Black,bookmarksopen,bookmarksopenlevel=1]{hyperref}
%
```

then I get:

[image]

Comment: I get this error: ! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package hyperref. See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for exp

Comment: I don't get this option clash with your MWE. Are you running the same code as your MWE above, plus only the bookmarkopenlevel=0 option as shown? If you have other packages/options that you have added, they may cause this.

Comment: Confirmed that this DOES address the difference **on opening first time** in SumatraPDF (which remembers **last bookmark status** thus will change on next run to **whatever you last expanded**) thus **after user interference** bookmarks may in some viewers not behave as author expected, however that is to be expected as normal.